# Select from multiple tables and combine into single row of temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have three tables (`FuelRates_Petrol`, `FuelRates_LPG` and `FuelRates_Diesel`) that use the same structure:

```
| OrganisationID | Band1 | Band2 | Band3 | ModifiedDate        |
|----------------|-------|-------|-------|---------------------|
| 1              | 10    | 12    | 19    | 01/05/2016 19:23:21 |
| 2              | 11    | 12    | 20    | 02/05/2016 19:23:21 |
```

I need to create a stored procedure that will select the record from each table with a matching `OrganisationID`. There will be one matching record in each table.

I then need to combine the results into a temporary table with the following structure and return it:

```
| OrganisationID | Petrol_Band1 | Petrol_Band2 | Petrol_Band3 | LPG_Band1 | LPG_Band2 | LPG_Band3 | Diesel_Band1 | Diesel_Band2 | Diesel_Band3 | ModifiedDate        |
|----------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
| 1              | 10           | 12           | 19           | 10        | 12        | 19        | 10           | 12           | 19           | 01/05/2016 19:23:21 |
```

The `Band1` column from the `FuelRates_Petrol` table should be inserted into the `Petrol_Band1` column of the `FuelRates` temporary table. The rest of the columns should follow this convention to create a single row as shown above.

SQL isn't really my bag but this was my effort:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FuelRates_RetrieveList] 
    @OrganisationID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #FuelRates(
    OrganisationID int,
    Petrol_Band1 int, 
    Petrol_Band2 int,
    Petrol_Band3 int,
    LPG_Band1 int,
    LPG_Band2 int,
    LPG_Band3 int,
    Diesel_Band1 int,
    Diesel_Band2 int,
    Diesel_Band3 int,
    ModifiedDate DateTime)

    SELECT Band1 As Petrol_Band1, Band2 As Petrol_Band2, Band3 As Petrol_Band3, ModifiedDate, OrganisationID FROM [FuelRates_Petrol]
    WHERE OrganisationID = @OrganisationID
    INSERT INTO #FuelRates

    SELECT Band1 As LPG_Band1, Band2 As LPG_Band2, Band3 As LPG_Band3 FROM [FuelRates_LPG]
    WHERE OrganisationID = @OrganisationID
    INSERT INTO #FuelRates

    SELECT Band1 As Diesel_Band1, Band2 As Diesel_Band2, Band3 As Diesel_Band3 FROM [FuelRates_Diesel]
    WHERE OrganisationID = @OrganisationID
    INSERT INTO #FuelRates

    SELECT * FROM #FuelRates

    DROP TABLE #FuelRates
END
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FuelRates_RetrieveList, Line 33
>   Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match
>   table definition.

Line 33 is `Diesel_Band1 int,` in the temp table create block.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

What is causing this error and am I even going about this in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this ...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FuelRates_RetrieveList] 
    @OrganisationID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #FuelRates(
    OrganisationID int,
    Petrol_Band1 int, 
    Petrol_Band2 int,
    Petrol_Band3 int,
    LPG_Band1 int,
    LPG_Band2 int,
    LPG_Band3 int,
    Diesel_Band1 int,
    Diesel_Band2 int,
    Diesel_Band3 int,
    ModifiedDate DateTime)

    INSERT INTO #FuelRates
    (OrganisationID, Petrol_Band1, Petrol_Band2, Petrol_Band3,LPG_Band1,LPG_Band2,LPG_Band3,
      Diesel_Band1, Diesel_Band2, Diesel_Band3, ModifiedDate)
    SELECT OrganisationID,
        p.Band1 As Petrol_Band1, p.Band2 As Petrol_Band2, p,Band3 As Petrol_Band3, 
        lp.Band1 As LPG_Band1, lp.Band2 As LPG_Band2, lp.Band3 As LPG_Band3,
        d.Band1 As Diesel_Band1, d.Band2 As Diesel_Band2, d.Band3 As Diesel_Band3,
        GetDate() as ModifiedDate
    FROM [FuelRates_Petrol] p
    LEFT JOIN FuelRates_LPG lp on lp.OrganisationID = p.OrganisationID
    LEFT JOIN FuelRates_Diesel d on d.OrganizationID = p.OrganisationID
    WHERE p.OrganisationID = @OrganisationID

    SELECT * FROM #FuelRates

    DROP TABLE #FuelRates
END
```

Comment: This is why I love SO! Thanks. This works a treat. Though you have a syntax error in the SELECT (`p,Band3 As Petrol_Band3` - comma instead of period)

Answer (score 2):

I know it says that the error is on line 33 which you have attributed to the `Diesel_Band1` but directly after that is the message:

> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

The `INSERT` method for SQL Server for defined tables is to place the insert statement first.

When you are not inserting the exact number of columns in the exact same order as the defined table then you need to define the columns and the order.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)
```

Change your inserts into the following:

```
INSERT INTO #FuelRates
    (Petrol_Band1, Petrol_Band2, Petrol_Band3, ModifiedDate, OrganisationID)
    SELECT Band1 As Petrol_Band1, Band2 As Petrol_Band2, Band3 As Petrol_Band3, ModifiedDate, OrganisationID 
    FROM [FuelRates_Petrol]
    WHERE OrganisationID = @OrganisationID
```

Comment: Thanks Shaneis. My code now looks like this: http://pastebin.com/kGM7kSQa which produces 3 rows rather than the one I'm after. Any way I can combine this in to a single row?

Comment: J Greene's answer was what I was going to go with. The only caveat is I would make sure that the table directly after the `FROM` has a record for OrganizationID, otherwise even if the other tables have a record, nothing will get returned.